# Change timezone to UTC in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

**Is it possible to change all dates and times to UTC instead of local timezone in the AWS console for my account?**

The timezone is UTC when using the AWS CLI, but always in my local timezone in the console. It is redundant for me to have to calculate times each time when comparing with server or colleagues times.

There is no option to change the timezone in the unified settings section.

Comment: There is a feedback option on the bottom of AWS console page, use it to suggest them to add this feature.

Comment: So that means it is currently not possible to do it @Azize?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe if you change your browser to UTC time zone. But if you can't find an option, give them a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do that is to change the browser/os' timezone.